Thermal efficiency circuit to move an DC electric actuator with PWM
I am looking for a circuit to move an electric actuator with PWM.
The actuator is 12V (datasheet) and the normal operating current is ~2A but can reach 8A maximum under some conditions. For that reason the circuit must move 8A safetly.
The main problem is the heat. I don't have any idea how to dissipate the least possible in case it's needed (not much room for a large heatsink or ventilation.)
My first idea is to use a N-CH MOSFET driven by PWM from the MCU.
Other possible options are:

P-CH MOSFET
PNP Darlington
NPN Darlington
Any better

Challenge: Avoid heatsink
What about that?


How much heat can you dissipate?

I can put a small heatsink if needed but the smaller as possible

Are you just doing on/off control?  Do you need to adjust the speed? Or change direction?

I must adjust the position (angle) in fact that actuator moves in one direction, more current more angle. On PWM 0 the actuator moves back by a spring inside.

I would just use a logic-level N-channel MOSFET as shown. 1 kΩ for the gate resistor is a bit high, try dropping it to 200 Ω or so depending on your MCU's current handling capability, or use a dedicated driver. You want quick transitions to minimize the amount of time you spend in the heat-producing intermediate state. In a TO-220 package, each 1 mΩ increase in Rds(on) only gives you a steady state Tj rise of ~4.5C above ambient so it shouldn't be too hard to find something that works.
I cannot speak to the PWM frequency, try asking the manufacturer directly.

Theoretically, with properly designed PWM, the power dissipation in the MOSFET should be very low, not requiring a large heat sink.
There are three power states:

Off: The MOSFET has very high resistance, many megohms to gigohms, and the current flow is very low, though there is a 12 V drop across it. E.G., 12 V * 0.000,000,01 A = 0.000,000,12 W
On: The MOSFET has very low resistance, a fraction of an ohm. E.G., the IRFZ44N is rated 48 A, 55 V, has  on-resistance, Rds(on) of 0.024 ohm. At 8 A, the power dissipation (I2R) is ~1.5 W, but you state that is a worst-case scenario (e.g., locked rotor). At 2 A, the dissipation is just ~0.1 W.
Intermediate (linear) state: While switching, as much as half the power could be split between motor and MOSFET. For a 12 V, 4 A load (half voltage across motor, half on MOSFET, the worst case), that would be ~24 W... but, in a well designed circuit, that only occurs for a very small fraction of the time. If the MOSFET circuit can switch in 1 µs, and the PWM runs at 10 kHz,  then it would be in an intermediate state ~1% of the time, and would dissipate at most 24 W * 0.01 = 0.24 W during that time.

So, given the estimates above, during off state, power dissipation can be ignored, and during full on with locked rotor at 8 A, if one percent of the time is in transition, maximum dissipation would be 1.5 W + 0.24 W. A heat sink capable of transferring 2 W to the environment would be sufficient.

that sounds good 2W heat sink is acceptable. Could I drive the IRFZ44N with a 3.3V PWM signal from my MCU directly?

That MOSFET was just an example; you'd have to emulate the circuit, taking into account gate capacitance (requiring driving current), etc. Start with spec sheets at https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/mosfet/n-channel/irfz44n/ for that particular device, or look at other MOSFETS's.

N-CH Mosfet has more heat efficency than a P-CH? or both  are the same?
